# Restrict search to component's field value with grails searchable plugin

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, searchable, grails-searchable

I have issue with restriction on component't field. My model structures are below

```
class Category {

    String name;
    String description;
    Date createDate

    static hasMany = [items: Item]

    static searchable = true
}
```

and

```
class Item {

    String name
    String description
    Category category

    static belogsTo = Category

    static searchable = {
        name boost: 2.0
        description boost: 2.0
        category component: true

        content: spellCheck 'include'
    }
}
```

below is my query

```
def items = Item.search({
    must(queryString(key))
    must(term('$/Item/category/name', category))
    //must(term('Item.category.name', category))
}, sort: params.sort, order: "asc").results;
```

Here the search results always empty. Is there something I am missing? I tried with "." and the other "$" options and no luck.

Comment: Are you sure that your index is built properly? Quite often, it is that trivial.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How can I verify this? Other fields, I am able to search. So it should be doing

Comment: Make a call to searchableService.reindex() from a controller you create specifically for reindexing. Possibly, the Searchable plugin provides such a controller, I am just not aware of it.

Comment: I had put searchableService.reindexAll() before search,  but no luck.